# Unable to pass template data to golang container with embedded FS

Tags: go

I am trying to containerise my Golang application using Docker swarm.

I noticed that in my local computer, the template data is passed properly, however, inside the container, it seems that the template data is not being passed. I am using embedded FS to store the template and using Caddy to proxy pass to the front-end service (if it's relevant).

Just wondering if anyone has encountered this issue, thank you very much in advance! Additionally it seems that using `{{print .BrokerURL "/handle"}}` does NOT automatically add double quote in the `fetch()` function which also results in error...

Please find below the relevant code and file:

`File structure`
[image]

`Makefile`

```
FRONT_BINARY=frontEndApp

# Build the binary
env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ${FRONT_BINARY} ./cmd/web
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN mkdir /app

COPY frontEndApp /app

CMD ["/app/frontEndApp"]
```

`DockerSwarm.yml`

```
front-end:
    image: front-end:1.0.1
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      BROKER_URL: "http://backend"
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Only / because we only have 1 page
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        render(w, "test.page.gohtml")
    })

    fmt.Println("Starting front end service on port 8081")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}

// embed templates folder to read only filesystem
//
//go:embed templates
var templateFS embed.FS

func render(w http.ResponseWriter, t string) {
    // Go template files to be parsed together with the given template
    partials := []string{
        "templates/base.layout.gohtml",
        "templates/header.partial.gohtml",
        "templates/footer.partial.gohtml",
    }

    // Add the page to the slice
    var templateSlice []string
    templateSlice = append(templateSlice, fmt.Sprintf("templates/%s", t))

    // Combine the templates with the page
    for _, x := range partials {
        templateSlice = append(templateSlice, x)
    }

    // Parse the page and templates
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFS(templateFS, templateSlice...)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    var data struct {
        BrokerURL string
    }
    data.BrokerURL = os.Getenv("BROKER_URL")

    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

`base.layout.gohtml`

```
{{define "base" }}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    {{template "header" .}}

    <body>

    {{block "content" .}}

    {{end}}

    {{block "js" .}}

    {{end}}

    {{template "footer" .}}

    </body>
    </html>

{{end}}
```

`footer.partial.gohtml`

```
{{define "footer"}}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <hr>
                <small class="text-muted">Copyright &copy;</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{end}}
```

`header.partial.gohtml`

```
{{define "header"}}

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Microservices in Go</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>

{{end}}
```

`test.page.gohtml`

```
{{define "js"}}
    <script>
        ...

        brokerBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const body = {
                method: "POST",
            };

            {{/* Since in golang template, need to use http:\/\/ */}}
            fetch({{.BrokerURL}}, body)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                sent.innerHTML = "empty post request"
                {{/* Get good formatted json */}}
                received.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
                if (data.error) {
                    console.log(data.message)
                } else {
                    output.innerHTML += `<br><strong>Response from broker service</strong>: ${data.message}`
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                output.innerHTML += `<br><br>Error: ${error}`
            });
        })

        authBrokerBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const payload = {
                action: "auth",
                auth: {
                    email: "admin@example.com",
                    password: "verysecret",
                }
            };

            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

            const body = {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(payload),
                headers: headers,
            }

            {{/* Since in golang template, need to use http:\/\/ */}}
            fetch({{print .BrokerURL "/handle"}}, body)
            ...
```

`relevant Caddyfile (if it helps)`

```
(static) {
    @static {
        file
        path *.ico *.css *.js *.gif *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.svg *.woff *.json
    }
    header @static Cache-Control max-age=5184000
}

# Specify the server
localhost:80 {
    encode zstd gzip # making the file as small as possible
    import static # import previously defined static block

    reverse_proxy  http://front-end:8081 
}

backend:80 {
    reverse_proxy http://broker-service:8080
}
```

`template data passed properly when running on local computer but error since {{print .BrokerURL "/handle"}} not enclosed with double quote`
[image]

`template data NOT passed on docker swarm (I have confirmed that the env variable is indeed already set in the container...)`
[image]